# How to create different types of number sequences using Scala's Fibionacci?

Tags: scala

How to create various types of number sequences based on previous values, like in Scala's [Fibonacci Stream example](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream)?

`x4, /2`, e.g. => `10 40 20 80 40 160`

**Test**

```
test("numbersequence") {
  assert(Calculation.numbersequence(10, 40, 20, 80) === 160)
}
```

**Main**

```
def numbersequence(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int) : Int = {
  lazy val s: Stream[Int] = a #:: s.scanLeft(b)(_+_)
  s(5)
}
```

Could the same approach be used to create such number sequences or should another approach be used?

Comment: Is your intention to create a stream of numbers which depend on previous values, as in the [Scala Stream documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream)?

Comment: Yes, that is the intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
val s: Stream[Int] = {
  def timesFour(v: Int): Stream[Int] = v #:: half(v * 4)
  def half(v: Int): Stream[Int] = v #:: timesFour(v / 2)
  timesFour(a)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are referring to the Fibonacci example in the [Scala Stream documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream).

Of course any simple rule on the previous value will work:

```
val doubles: Stream[Long] = 1l #:: 2 #:: doubles.tail.map (_ * 2)
```

Note that you need at least 2 starting values for this technique, otherwise .tail will result in infinite recursion.

If you want to create a stream with alternating rules, you could use flatMap instead of map to create multiple values:

```
object streams {

  val alternatingRule: Stream[Long] = 1l #:: 4l #:: alternatingRule.tail.flatMap { n => 
    val n1 = n * 4
    val n2 = n1 / 2 
    n1 #:: n2 #:: Stream.Empty 
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println(alternatingRule(5))
    println(alternatingRule.take(10).toList)
  }

}
```

Comment: Several errors occur when I run the sample. Should `l` be passed? How does it look like in a function? Could it be wrapped into e.g. `def numbersequence2() : Double = { ... }`?

Comment: When placing `lazy` in front of it the `val doubles` sample works.

Comment: Running the second sample results in: `found   : x$12.type (with underlying type Long)
required: A
 n1 #:: n2 #:: Stream.Empty`

Comment: It works for me exactly as pasted, for example when using it in `println(alternatingRule.take(10).toList)`. `l` marks a number as long, it is not a variable.

Comment: I updated with a self-contained object, please try running that.

Comment: When this test `assert(NumberSequences.numbersequence2() === 16)` is run this error occurs: `[error]  found   : x$12.type (with underlying type Long)
[error]  required: A
[error]     n1 #:: n2 #:: Stream.Empty
[error]               ^
[error] one error found`

Comment: I would need to see the definition of numbersequence2 to help with this.

Comment: `def numbersequence2() : Long = {
    val alternatingRule: Stream[Long] = 1l #:: 4l #:: alternatingRule.tail.flatMap { n => 
      val n1 = n * 4
      val n2 = n1 / 2 
      n1 #:: n2 #:: Stream.Empty 
    }
    alternatingRule(5)
  }`

Comment: alright, I could reproduce your error. Moving the definition of `alternatingRule` outside the `numbersequence2` function and making it a `lazy val` makes it work, though I honestly can't say why.